# Configuring Telegram on BQ Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, telegram

Before switching to the Ubuntu phone, I tested Telegram on my old Android phone. Here I was able to change the profile picture as wel as the sound of the notifications.
On the BQ phone, under settings, there is no option to change the notification signal and I cannot change the picture. (I'm using Telegram for Ubuntu v1.3.10 (102)). Should I delete (uninstall) Telegram from my old phone (is there somehow a connection via the cloud?) or is the option not available in Telegram for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely change your profile picture in Telegram on Ubuntu-touch.

In order to do so:

1. Open Telegram
2. Go into settings (upper right, last point in the
       menu)
3. Upper right you see a picture icon > Clicking this you get
       to choose the app you want to take your picture from

The notification signal you get for Telegram seems to be the same as you chose for your short messages, although it seems not to work for all available sounds (for Mallet it works for me).